# The response time is set too small, resulting in read time out in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

[image]

After the response time is set too small, check the result tree and display read time out,But not all fail, some don't show read time out.
There is no problem with the server returning the result. It should be the problem of jmeter, please help me analyze.

jmeter log:

```
2022-03-01 15:25:22,959 DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: Sent 314 bytes
2022-03-01 15:25:23,011 DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: IOException
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [SocketTimeoutException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) description:

> Signals that a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept.

**You're expecting JMeter to get the response in 50 milliseconds** or less, if the server fails to respond fully in 50 milliseconds - you will get this error.

If you're absolutely sure that your server responds in less than 50 milliseconds be aware that there are also [connect time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) and [latency](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0)

As per [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> Elapsed time. **JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received**. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.

So there are following operations involved:

1. JMeter connects to the server
2. JMeter sends the request
3. Server prepares the response
4. Server sends the response to the server
5. JMeter receives first byte of the response
6. JMeter receives last byte of the response

And "Response timeout" means full end-to-end sequence.

If you don't want to see this error either increase the timeout or use [Duration Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) instead, in that case JMeter will wait for the full response to arrive and only then will assert whether the response time exceeds the anticipated value